# How is the derivative of this function at $x$ the map itself?

Tags: analysis

I'm getting quite confused by something that is perhaps not that confusing. I know that if you have a function $f(x) = ax$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f'(x) = a$, i.e. the derivative is $f$.

In that circumstance, I know *what* $f$ is, namely $f = a$. However, considering the map: $$F(x) = \int_0^1x(t)\ dt$$ If you go through the calculations you arrive at the conclusion that $DF(x) = F$ but what is $F$? I don't find this completely analogous to the first case I gave above and hard to understand intuitively. Please could somebody help?

Comment: What do you mean when you write $DF(x) = F$? Note that in your definition of $F$, $x$ is itself a function; so $F$ is a mapping which takes integrable functions on $[0,1]$ to numbers.

Comment: I mean that because the derivative is a linear map which satisfies $F(x + h) - F(x) - DF(x)(h) \leq \epsilon |h|$ it follows that $DF(x) := F$, no? So my question is, how do you imagine what $F$ is analogous to the case when $f(x) = ax$?

Comment: Thn in "physical" terms: $t$ is *time* and $x(t)$ is the position (function of time) along a rectilinear path, and draw the graph.

Comment: Can you precisely state what you denote as $DF(x)$ ?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I just want it to symbolise the linear map which corresponds to the derivative. I could've used $A$ or anything else. Am I wrong here?

Comment: The point of the derivative is that $f(x + h) \approx f(x) + Df|_x h$. Here $Df_x$ is a linear operator. If $f$ is linear function, then the $\approx$ becomes $=$ and $Df_x$ is the same linear operator as $f$, since $f(x + h) = f(x) + f(h)$. Similarly, here you have $F(x+h) = F(x) + F(h)$, so $DF|_x "=" F$, which means that if you add something small called $h$ to $x$ (which here probably means $h$ has small absolute integral, though you haven't defined a norm) then the integral of $x+h$ will differ by approximately (exactly) the integral of $x$ by the integral of $h$.

Comment: Ok I sort of understand what you're saying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general: let $(X, ||*||)$ be a normed space and $F: X \to \mathbb R$ a bounded linear functional on $X$. For $x \in X$ we have

$ \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{F(x+y)-F(x)-F(y)}{||y||}=0$.

This means that $F$ is differentiable at $x$ and $DF(x)=F$.

In your situation above we have $X=C[0,1]$ with the max-norm and $F(x) = \int_0^1x(t)\ dt$